# Embed a Youtube video in Android app

Tags: java, android, video, webview, youtube

I'm trying to embed a Youtube video in a WebView, and I want to support Android version 2.
Since Google owns both Android and Youtube, I thought it would be easy, but apparently it's not. I've seen similar questions but they didn't help.

On Android 2.1 when I tap the play button, I have the message "An error occurred, please try again later."

On Android 2.3 I have player buttons but the video does not start.

Here is my code:

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends Activity {
  private WebView webView;
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    webView = new WebView (this);
    setContentView (webView);
    webView.getSettings ().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient ());
    webView.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient () {
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl (url);
        return true;
      }
    });
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
      webView.getSettings ().setPluginsEnabled (true);
    }
    else {
      webView.getSettings ().setPluginState (PluginState.ON);
    }
    webView.loadUrl ("http://youtube.com/embed/NAg4qXsk99c?rel=0");
  }
  protected void onPause () {
    super.onPause ();
    webView.loadUrl ("about:blank");
  }
}
```

I also added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml.

The Youtube Android Player API is not an option for me because I also want to support platforms without the Youtube app (like Amazon, Blackberry...).

I also tried with RTSP links but the quality is too bad.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not use Youtube Android Player API?

Comment: @TeRRo Because I want to show other views beside the video. And as I said, I want to support also Android version 2.

Comment: Do you know about appyet.com ?

Comment: @VijayBarbhaya This does not answer my question.